# AttributeError: 'nt.DirEntry' object has no attribute 'rstrip'

Tags: python

```
from os import scandir, rename
from os.path import splitext, exists, join
from shutil import move
from time import sleep

import logging

from watchdog.observers import Observer
from watchdog.events import FileSystemEventHandler

# ! FILL IN BELOW
# ? folder to track e.g. Windows: "C:\\Users\\UserName\\Downloads"
source_dir = "C:\\Users\\PC\\Downloads"
dest_dir_image = "C:\\Users\\PC\\Music"

# ? supported image types
image_extensions = [".jpg", ".jpeg", ".jpe", ".jif", ".jfif", ".jfi", ".png", ".gif", ".webp", ".tiff", ".tif", ".psd", ".raw", ".arw", ".cr2", ".nrw",
                    ".k25", ".bmp", ".dib", ".heif", ".heic", ".ind", ".indd", ".indt", ".jp2", ".j2k", ".jpf", ".jpf", ".jpx", ".jpm", ".mj2", ".svg", ".svgz", ".ai", ".eps", ".ico"]

def make_unique(dest, name):
    filename, extension = splitext(name)
    counter = 1
    # * IF FILE EXISTS, ADDS NUMBER TO THE END OF THE FILENAME
    while exists(f"{dest}/{name}"):
        name = f"{filename}({str(counter)}){extension}"
        counter += 1

    return name


def move_file(dest, entry, name):
    move(entry, dest)


class MoverHandler(FileSystemEventHandler):
    # ? THIS FUNCTION WILL RUN WHENEVER THERE IS A CHANGE IN "source_dir"
    # ? .upper is for not missing out on files with uppercase extensions
    def on_modified(self, event):
        with scandir(source_dir) as entries:
            for entry in entries:
                name = entry.name
                self.check_image_files(entry, name)


    def check_image_files(self, entry, name):  # * Checks all Image Files
        for image_extension in image_extensions:
            if name.endswith(image_extension) or name.endswith(image_extension.upper()):
                move_file(dest_dir_image, entry, name)
                logging.info(f"Moved image file: {name}")


# ! NO NEED TO CHANGE BELOW CODE
if __name__ == "__main__":
    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO,
                        format='%(asctime)s - %(message)s',
                        datefmt='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    path = source_dir
    event_handler = MoverHandler()
    observer = Observer()
    observer.schedule(event_handler, path, recursive=True)
    observer.start()
    try:
        while True:
            sleep(10)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        observer.stop()
    observer.join()
```

No matter what I do i keep getting the same error AttributeError: 'nt.DirEntry' object has no attribute 'rstrip'
Im new to coding and copied this off a youtuber. No matter what i change cmd gives me the same error. I dont know what the problem is and cant find anything online

Comment: Please show the traceback, because there's nothing in your code called `nt.DirEntry`, so it must be something being called from your code via some method you call. The traceback will show the line that's causing this.

Comment: "C:\Users\PC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\shutil.py", line 526, in _basename
    return os.path.basename(path.rstrip(sep))
AttributeError: 'nt.DirEntry' object has no attribute 'rstrip'

Answer (score 0):

Try to add to shutil.py file this line:

```py
path = os.fspath(path)
```

BEFORE:

```py
def _basename(path):

     sep = os.path.sep + (os.path.altsep or '')

    return os.path.basename(path.rstrip(sep))
```

AFTER:

```py
def _basename(path):

    path = os.fspath(path)

    sep = os.path.sep + (os.path.altsep or '')

    return os.path.basename(path.rstrip(sep))
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).